# Javascript animation libraries that don't use the DOM?

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm looking for a Javascript animation library that doesn't use the DOM, so I can use it with Titanium when I'm not working inside a webview. Inside a webview, I can use whatever I want. But outside of that, I need an animation library that doesn't assume there is a DOM.

Comment: exactly what will you be manipulating?

Comment: Then how would it manipulate the dom?

Comment: I want to manipulate JS objects in Titanium, but not in a webview. If I was working inside a webview, I could just use anything like jQuery and I'd be all set. But I'm using some other native UI elements, so I want to stay outside a webview, where there is no DOM, just objects.

Comment: An example might be to manipulate myTest.image { left: 10, top: 100 } to a new position, using an easing equation.

Comment: +1 - This doesn't deserve so many down votes.  It's a perfectly valid question -- he's asking how to animate properties on an object.

Comment: This question makes little sense to me.  When I search on Titanium, I find a cross platform development tool that supports HTML5 and CSS3 and javascript.  How could it support those and not have a DOM?  In your one example, you're talking about an image object with CSS properties.  Isn't that part of a DOM?  How is the Titanium environment different than a normal web page?  How can it not have a DOM?

Comment: @jfriend00 - TitaniumUI renders javascript into native phone elements; there is no DOM.  e.g. it takes a call to `createButtonBar()`, and instead of creating a DIV with images in it, it creates an iPhone button bar (or an android one).

Comment: Titanium can work on the DOM inside a webview for a Desktop or Mobile app, or outside the DOM for a Mobile app, or a mix of both, on a Mobile app. Mobile apps that are "100% native" don't use the webviews, but instead has an API to create objects. In that mode, there is no DOM, no HTML, no CSS, etc.

Comment: Then, you should state this as a Titanium-specific question.  Apparently, you need a javascript library that works on Titanium objects via their API.  If the objects don't have the properties and methods of a web DOM, then you need a library that is explicitly written for the Titanium development environment and you shuold state your question as a Titanium-API-specific question so that it is clear that this question is only directed at those who know about the Titanium API and plug-ins/libraries written specifically for it.  Rather than saying "doesn't use the DOM", say what API it should use.

Comment: It wasn't a Titanium-specific question so I didn't tag it as such at first. I was hoping to find something portable from outside the Titanium sphere, but that doesn't look likely now. Looks like I'll have to start with some standard tweening libraries, as stated below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist is that you want a basic tweening library, [like this one](https://github.com/sole/tween.js).  Basically it animates  any properties on an object instead of on DOM elements.

Also, per docs, Titanium UI has [built-in animations](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Animations+in+Action)

Comment: The built-in animations are very limited, hence the reason I'm looking to work outside of them. There are some show-stopping bugs regarding nested or chained animations which drove me to look elsewhere and explore external options. It does in fact look like I need a tweening library or at least the set of equations to work into my own class.